# Vertex Baking to textures for Colour ID Map not working 2.79

Tags: texture-baking, baking, vertex-paint

I don't understand, Only yesterday this baked out just fine and as far as I can tell, I never changed anything.

Blender render

*Add 1 material to model* - UV unwrap model - Vertex paint mode and paint each part of the mesh, eg hair, fur etc - select model in edit mode with face mode turned on - open new image in UV editor - bake to vertex colours, bake settings set to texture texture

but now it does nothing!

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: What Blender version, what render engine? What does material setup look like? What do you mean by *"Vertex paint each section"* and *"select model in face mode"*? You can [edit] the question with screenshots of settings and more description

Comment: Sounds alright to me, can you upload that file so we can have a look? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Can't upload, just keep getting errors